# Checking websphere mq installed in target computer?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, websphere, ibm-mq

How do i check whether IBM MQ client is installed in the client computer via vb.net winform application?

```
I have added amqmdnet.dll to my project and imported IBM.WMQ namespace.
```

However i don't know how to check IBM MQ client installed in the target computer? (like for example, if you want to check a windows service, you can loop through all the available services, then check for that particular windows service)

Any inputs will be highly helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dspmqver` command will let you know what is installed.

From the [Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317540):

> **CAUTION:** Do not use these APIs in your application to perform assembly
>   binds or to test for the presence of assemblies or other run time,
>   development, or design-time operations. Only administrative tools and
>   setup programs must use these APIs. If you use the GAC, this directly
>   exposes your application to assembly binding fragility or may cause
>   your application to work improperly on future versions of the .NET
>   Framework.

There is no native MQ API to check the GAC.  (Shashi, please correct me if I've overlooked something here. I know you are watching.  :-) )

Comment: Yes, but i need to directly check from code and not via command prompt, is there any method or attribute to check that?

Comment: Windows registry will also tell what version of MQ is installed on a system.